# Create a student-grade query from a relational database

Tags: ms-access, relations

I have three tables:
Students (Id, name)
Assessments (id, name, max_score)
StudentAssessment (Id, student_ID, assessment_id, score) where ids are FK from the other two tables.

I think this is the most effective way of storing my data.

I want a Query that produces

Student Name|Assessment 1 score|Assessment 2 score|etc

Where Assessment 1, Assessment 2 are rows in the assessments table.

I'm not sure how to approach this (I'm a teacher trying to put together a better way of tracking progress not a professional programmer, I have a basic knowledge of relational db) and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Start by writing a simple join query that returns (Student Name, Assessment Name, Score)  Then consider how to display that result.  If you want the assessments on columns that's called a "pivot" or "crosstab" query.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at crosstab queries.

Comment: I guess a join like SELECT * FROM students INNER JOIN studentassessment ON student.id =studentassessment.id INNER JOIN assessment ON assessment.id = studentassessment.id WHERE assessment.id = "a value"